# AngularJS, multiple generated forms on page. How to get contents of forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a web page that generates forms to updates things over REST API on remote server. The forms are generated with PHP.

The forms are as follows:

```
Textfield: name
textfield: description
select: type (ng-model="selection")
  option a
  option b
  option c
textfields f1, f2, f3: some of these are hidden depending on the selection.
button that fires (update()) AngularJS when pressed.
```

There are multiple of such forms on the page.

How do I get the contents of the fields to pass to update() using AngularJS? I thought that I could use Javascript getElementById and do some magic to that stuff but I bet there would be a more beautiful way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS you can bind data to your form using the `ng-model` property.

Check out the example from the documentation:

```
 <form novalidate class="simple-form">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="reset()" value="Reset" />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save" />
  </form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qr1HdCqgr7jvf5aR0Gb2?p=preview

It is a good practice to have models being part of one object and only define properties on this object (in the form above, the model for your form data is the user object and each field is used to specify a property of this object, user.email for example).

Then, in your controller, you can access your form values through the corresponding scope variable ($scope.user in our example).

Answer (score 0):

You can set [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to each of the form fields. Inside `update` method you can access them using `$scope` object.

E.g

```
<input type="text" ng-model="form1.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="form1.description">
...
...

<input type="text" ng-model="form2.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="form2.description">
```

Js

In the `update` method you can access it using `$scope.form1.name`, `$scope.form1.description`

Answer (score 0):

You can create tabs where every tab will be one form (editing one item), clicking on one tab it will open you the current element and you can edit it. This way you do not need to know how many elements there will be.

```
<div ng-app>
    <article ng-controller="AplicationCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="changeSelected($index)">Tabs {{$index}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br/>
       <div>
           <input ng-model="selectedItem.name"/>
           <input ng-model="selectedItem.description"/>
        </div>

        <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="update()">Update values</a>
    </article>
</div>

function AplicationCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            name: 'this is name1',
            description: 'desc 1'
        },
        {
            name: 'this is name 2',
            description: 'desc 2'
        },
        {
            name: 'this is name 3',
            description: 'desc 4'
        }
    ]

    $scope.changeSelected = function (index) {
        $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[index];
    }

    $scope.changeSelected(0);

    $scope.update = function () {
        console.log($scope.items);
    }
}
```

you can look it at here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9c567te7/